# How to forward calls from Twilio IVR to SIP?

Tags: twilio, sip

I built the IVR on twilio. So when consumer calls in our phone number, it goes to that IVR app using twilio. Now we want to forward the call to the external third-party business. We can do that without any issues if the external third-party has phone number to forward to. But in this case, external third-party uses SIP and they want us to forward the call from IVR to their SIP.

When I try dialing SIP endpoint using  TwiML verb, it gives the following error saying -

> Your TwiML can only Dial out to Twilio SIP Domains that your account
>   owns

Do I need to setup SIP trunk for this simple use case?

Comment: Are you using a free account or have you upgraded?

Comment: Its upgraded business account.

Comment: Can you share the TwiML you're using, please?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Sip>sip:alice@external_sip_address.com</Sip>
    </Dial>
</Response>`

Comment: That is weird. I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who should be able to tell why your account is behaving like that.

Comment: Thanks @philnash

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the REST API to make outgoing SIP calls to external domains. You initiate the call with an HTTP POST containing your user credentials as well as the SIP address and a callback url.

The TwiML generated is the response from the server, you can't just serve it up yourself.

Full docs are [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls-sip)